# How can i install my PWA app through any link or any APP store, but not from handset browser

Tags: android, mobile, installation, progressive-web-apps, iso

Am a basic and a fresher developer in the code world. Am developed a PWA app and wants to install it from the Google Play Store or any other suitable method. Now a day's am just able to install my PWA-APP via the Chrome/Safari browser by typing the URL first, then a pop up appears automatically and ask to 'Add shortcut on home screen'. This is the standard way for installing a PWA app.

But can it possible to share a Link of my PWA-APP to my users or any other way for installing the PWA app ? I don't have such more ideas to do some other installation way and request a kind help to install the APP without depending on any browser.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: The only way to install a PWA is by using an HTTPS browser and having the user click on the yes for THAT "Add shortcut?" message. You can add your own logic to pop up that same message, but the user must say yes to THAT message.

Comment: Hi Mathias,

Thanks for your great reply. At present in my PWA the normal 'pop-up' arrives. It will be grateful for me if you please share some solution/code that how can i make a own customized 'Pop-UP' message for installing the PWA app.

The PWA which using both of Android and IOS on my case.

Comment: You cannot change the browser install message. But you can control when it pops up for Chrome. More info here. https://web.dev/customize-install/